# Challenges with mu4e contexts

Tags: mu4e

I recently started using emacs and mu/mu4e. And I like it!
Using mu4e 1.4.13.

When I started using contexts for my 2 mail accounts it introduces a couple of new problems:

1. First of all when I start mu4e it does not start, but gives this message:

   ```
   mu4e-error: [mu4e] root maildir unknown; did you start mu4e?
   ```

   However, loading mu4e the second time, it seems to start as normal.
   I use M-x mu4e to start mu4e, and I start it right after starting emacs.
2. If I switch from mu4e main view to another buffer, I can't switch back to the mu4e main view buffer. It is not showing in the buffer list anymore.

My mu4e-config looks very close to the example provided in the documentation.

Any ideas?

Comment: please, only one question by post. Anyway, you should include how you start mu4e, usually `M-x mu4e` or with a keybinding. Your message happens often if you try to compose mail before loading mu4e itself.  mu4e main view is either `*mu4e-main*` or `*mu4e-headers*` depending your last used view, bind mu4e to any key and you'll get it back quickly.

Comment: Could you post a followup with maybe a copy of your config, please? Issues with contexts seem very common, but there's very little followup and confirmed fixes.